# How to exit full screen in chromium if using tocuh scrren

Tags: raspbian, chromium

How to exit full screen in chromium programmatically?

Here is my scenario:

1. Running this command when raspbian startup

   ```
   chromium-browser --start-fullscreen -incognito http://ooxx.com/index.html
   ```
2. Basically this html contain only a `.png` image
3. We use touch panel (no keyboard and mouse)

Is there anyway I can create a `<div>`, and allow user to tap it and run some script to exit full screen mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate keypress (F11) via JavaScript.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-simulate-a-keypress-event-in-JavaScript